# Regex match for tags within tags and last matching tag

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to parse some xml tags with data containing Escaped strings
Some samples

```
other tags with our without newlines
<tag name="abc1" type="bcd" value="test"><tag name="abc2" type="bcd" value="test">  
other tags other tags with our without newlines
<tag name="abc2" type="bcd" value="<w:test xmlns:wst=&quot;http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust&quot;><a xmlns:&quot;a:b:c:ddd:&quot;>XEduAjr8MoV</a></w:test>">
```

basically I need to find values in tags within other strings. Something like this

```
<tag name="wwww" type="wwww" value="SOME HTML ESCAPED STRING WITH NEWLINES">
```

Here is what I have

```
<tag name="(?<name>\w*)" type="(?<id>\w*)" value="(?<value>.*)">
```

I am using this c# code

```
var regex = new Regex(regstr, RegexOptions.Multiline);
MatchCollection mc = regex.Matches(sourcestring);
```

I am running into problems with multiple matches combined because of `(?<value>.*)` for if both are same line `<tag name="abc1" type="bcd" value="test"><tag name="abc2" type="bcd" value="test">` Any way to get around this? Is there any better way?

Comment: You better don't parse xml/html using regexes... Use xslt...

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's well known that you **should not use** regex to parse xhtml, unless you don't have complex tags and a weird set of characters.

However, if you want to use regex, for your specific example, you have to use **non greedy** (or lazy) quantifiers:

```
<tag name="(?<name>\w*?)" type="(?<id>\w*?)" value="(?<value>.*?)">
                                                       HERE ---^
also I put it here ---^------------------^ 
since it is more secure, but it is not needed
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/kT6gA9/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Its not advisable to parse xml files with regex patterns. A reason for this is because xml involves/requires deep nesting.